# How can I figure out which branch of a Process Builder/Flow relates to the Current Element 'myWait_myRule_20'

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow

The Flow setup page contains a list of `Paused and Waiting Interviews`

One of the columns is `Current Element` for example:

> myWait_myRule_20

How can I match that to a branch of the Process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can debug it by downloading metadata using workbench.

Create a file named package.xml with below content. The flowName and its version number

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <fullName>MyPackage</fullName>


    <types>
        <members>OffeningFlow-48</members>
        <name>Flow</name>
    </types>
    <version>44.0</version>
</Package>
```

Go to workbench / Force.com migration tool(Alternatively you can use an IDE) and select your package.xml. Dont forget to check single package.
[image]

Once downloaded, it will include your flow metadata. It will also show the name of the offending block that you got in an exception. 
[image]

Comment: Thanks. Can I download this information via SFDX / VS Code also?

Comment: Hi @Robs , yes you can. They are part of metadata name as flow.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to deduce the element:

1. Create a Temporary Picklist or text field to update prior to the scheduled action being created.
2. Edit/Create the record to meet the Criteria for the immediate test picklist to be updated and the scheduled action to occur.
3. Then go into the Paused Flows and the value in the Paused Flows is the one that fired the immediate action and will be for every subsequent update.